# Using Visio to present SharePoint 2007 sites and permissions (or is there a SP webpart to do this)

Tags: permissions, visio

I am Using Visio 2013 Web Site Map to create a visual representation of the SP2007 Site and folders.  I need to incorporate showing permission groups (showing broken inheritances too). There does not seem to an automated way to do this.  I hate to resort to manually typing in the permission groups. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2007, there is the SharePoint Administration Toolkit which has a [Permissions Reporting Tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2009/09/02/sharepoint-administration-toolkit-v4-for-moss-2007.aspx).

If you need the Visio aspect, you could possibly try taking the output of this into a data connection in Visio.